# Comparing keys from dictionaries to a list of strings and summing the values

Tags: python, dictionary

so I have made a dictionary, the keys are words and the values are numerical values associated to each of the words. I also have a list of words. I want to take the words in the list and see if any of them are in the dictionary. If words from the list are in the dictionary, I need to be able to add up the values associated with each of the words.

```
dictionary = {"happy": 5, "greatest": 10, "best": 5, "excited": 10}
list = ["I", "am", "so", "happy", "this", "is", "the", "greatest", "day", "ever", "I", "am", "so", "excited", "!"]
```

Comment: I'd write a simple for loop stepping through each word in the list, with an if-statement. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: using list comprehension this is simple: `sum([dictionary[i] for i in list if i in dictionary])`

Comment: You really should make an attempt and post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension:

```
dictionary = {"happy": 5, "greatest": 10, "best": 5, "excited": 10}
lst = ["I", "am", "so", "happy", "this", "is", "the", "greatest", "day", "ever", "I", "am", "so", "excited", "!"]

print sum([dictionary[i] for i in lst if i in dictionary])
```

Comment: You could also use a generator expression instead of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`get`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) on a [**`dict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) with a default value to return if the key doesn't exist.

Also, dictionary and list are not good variable names, even in an example:

```
>>> weights = {"happy": 5, "greatest": 10, "best": 5, "excited": 10}
>>> sentence = 'I am so happy this is the greatest day ever I am so excited !'

>>> sum(weights.get(word, 0) for word in sentence.split())
20
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use list as variable name (it's a keyword)

This code does what you want:

```
sum_value = 0
for item in list1:
    if item in dictionary:
        sum_value += dictionary[item]
```

Comment: Revised to solve the problem. Iteration is correct, but your summation was not correct :)

Comment: @DavidZemens : sure tnx